# Detect if the user is holding a file then show a window

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I want to detect if the user is holding a file, if he is i want to show a window that will take this file and move it to another folder.

The window itself i done, i just need to detect if the user has dragged a file (anywhere on the screen, i can't detect it on the window because the window isn't shown.), then show the window (with `window.show()`).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add information on what you have already tried as well as a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Another thing - you can edit your question instead of adding comments to add information or clarify things

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the drag events documentation for javascript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API#Drag_Events

Elements that are draggable, has the `draggable=true` property and an `ondragstart` event handler

from the documentation:

```
<script>
function dragstart_handler(ev) {
 // Add the target element's id to the data transfer object
 ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ev.target.id);
}
</script>

<p id="p1" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart_handler(event)">This element is draggable.</p>
```

Comment: it's electron, not on the browser.

Comment: You have to explain further what you mean with "the window is not shown"